# Order of operation evaluation in condition in Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, operator-precedence

If I have something like `a = [1,2,3]` and I write a statement like `1 in a == True`, that appears to evaluate to false.

However, if I write `(1 in a) == True`, that evaluates to true.

I am slightly confused about how Python evaluates the first statement to reach false in the end.

Comment: Why bother with the `== True` at all? I think something like `if 1 in a:` reads better anyway.

Comment: `1 in a == True` means `1 in a and a==True`. Search for _python operator chaining_

Comment: What did you not understand after working through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)?  We expect you to include that discovery in your posting.

Answer (score 1):

Both `==` and `in` are considered *comparison* operators, meaning that [operator chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) comes into effect:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

This chaining is what allows you to write:

```
if 0 <= x < 20: # meaning: if x >= 0 and x < 20:
```

Hence the expression `1 in a == True` is chained as `1 in a and a == True` and, since the right side of that `and` evaluates to false, the entire expression is false.

This chaining does not occur when you "isolate" part of the expression with parentheses, which is why `(1 in a) == True` acts as you expect.

---

Having explained that, comparing a boolean value with `True` (or `False` for that matter) is not really something you should be doing anyway, since that leads to logically infinite scenarios like:

```
if (((a == 7) == True) != False) == True # 'a == 7' already a boolean.
```

Far better just to use one of:

```
if expression        # if comparing with True
if not expression    # if comparing with False
```